# MUX for RFID 13.56 MHz

Tags: multiplexer, rfid, 13.56mhz

Working on a project that involves an array of RFID (HF 13.56 MHz) antennas using a single RFID transceiver.

In-order to switch between the antennas I'm looking for a 1:8 (or more) RF MUX.

As the frequency is relatively low, I was looking into standard analog MUX ICs like IC TMUX8109 as its spec specifies a bandwidth of 380 MHz or IC CD74HC4067 with a bandwidth of 89 MHz.

Would these ICs be suitable for switching 50 Ω 13.56 MHz RFID signal? If not, what would be the right way to do this task?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the power level? What loss can you accept through the switch (waste of TX power, increased RX noise)? There are specific 50 ohm RF switching products designed for antenna multiplex, typically for higher frequencies, but many will work down to a few MHz at low power level (Peregrine Semi). The series resistance of standard analogue muxes might well run you into a lot of insertion loss at 50 ohm, even if they are flat, the TMUX8109 is 38 ohm typical! Maxim and Analog Devices do some ohm-level analog switches, I'll wager TI does as well. But product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: As the output of the transceiver is 20db and I will probably have some margin on that so some loss of power is acceptable. The higher frequencies products might do the job very good but most have a high-pass and are rated 100Mhz minimum so they are out of the scope.

Comment: 20 db isn't a power level. Do you mean 20 dBm, or 20 dB with respect to something else? Yes, most 50 ohm switches are high pass, or don't handle low frequencies well, but some do go down to DC, albeit with a backing off of their typical 30 dBm power handling level, be thorough with your search

Comment: It could just be that you're looking under the wrong search terms. I can find plenty of devices listed under ["RF switches"](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rf-switches/865) that go all the way down to DC. You could make your mux out of a bunch of cheap SPDT switches, or you could spend more money for a [one-chip solution](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/HMC253AQS24ETR/5438045). Note that most of these can get arbitrarily close to DC, but can't actually reach DC because they need blocking capacitors on all RF ports.